# Any tools for saving web pages and related links to view offline?

Tags: windows, web

I am going on a vacation and will be bringing my laptop.
I am trying to read during wait time (at the air port) and flight
There are tons of articles to catch up.

What would be a good way to save web pages so that they can be viewed later on?
Should I save each web site as a PDF format?

Are there any tools that will save all related links (e.g. [F# wiki book](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming)) for wikis or any web site articles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IE (at least in version 8) you can save a web archive (File->Save As).

Comment: Currently installing IE8...

Answer (score 5):

You might also have a look at [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/), there are versions for several OS's. As I recall, it has a recursive mode that will allow you to mirror sites to your local machine.

Comment: For Windows users, or GUI-caring-persons, there's a nice interface to wget, called wwget. Worth a look.

Comment: @Moshe I thought I had to write a script to call wget... great to know that there is a GUI version. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

[HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/) will do what you want.

EDIT: If you are having problems with the latest 3.4x version, you might want to try 3.33 which you can download [here](http://download.httrack.com/cserv.php3?File=httrack-previous.exe) (or from a link at the bottom of the site's [download page](http://www.httrack.com/page/2/en/index.html).)  Sounds like there were some pretty big changes in 3.4x (I haven't had to use it for a while, and don't run Vista.)

Here are some links into the forums with regards to running on vista that might help too, but I'd try 3.33 first: [1](http://forum.httrack.com/readmsg/19734/19732/index.html), [2](http://forum.httrack.com/readmsg/18361/18360/index.html), [3](http://forum.httrack.com/readmsg/17480/index.html).

Comment: HTTrack seems quite buggy and i might save each page faster than getting around some of this programs problems...

Comment: I've never had any problems with it.  It has always worked well for me.

Comment: Download site doesn't mention "Vista" explicitly so I am wondering it has some issues for that reason...  I had it crashing like 10 times already...

Comment: @Sung Have added some more info to my answer that may help you. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

If this is content available over RSS, you might consider using [Google Reader](http://reader.google.com) with [Google Gears](http://gears.google.com/) for offline access.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [ScrapBook](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/427):

> ScrapBook is a Firefox extension,
>   which helps you to save Web pages and
>   easily manage collections. Key
>   features are lightness, speed,
>   accuracy and multi-language support.
>   Major features are:
>
> - Save Web page
> - Save snippet of Web page
> - Save Web site
> - Organize the collection in the same way as Bookmarks
> - Full text search and quick filtering search of the collection
> - Editing of the collected Web page
> - Text/HTML edit feature resembling Opera's Notes

Answer (score 0):

Re HTTrack, there is a Firefox Add-on/extension [SpiderZilla](http://spiderzilla.mozdev.org/), which gives you a GUI which in turn invokes HTTrack, I've never had any problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

[**Read It Later** (browser add-on).](http://readitlaterlist.com/)